# C# dynamically added GroupBox seems to be empty after adding controls to it

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with a little tool i am writing for myself.
I am trying to have a Windows Form that shows a web browser and multiple, dynamically added groups of textboxes and comboboxes.
The browser works fine and i can add textboxes etc. fine when not adding it to a groupbox, but rather to the main panel.

When trying to add the textboxes to groupboxes it works for the first groupbox, but every other one that followes stayes empty.

this is how my (simplified) code looks so far:

```
        //generate controls e.g.
        ComboBox dynamicComboBox = new ComboBox();
        dynamicComboBox.Name = "comboBox" + anzahlModule;
        dynamicComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(this.getInhaltComboBox(), null);
        dynamicComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
        dynamicComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
        dynamicComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(153, Yloc + 25);
        dynamicComboBox.TabIndex = tabReihenfolge + 2;
        dynamicComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

        ...do for all the others...


        //Get Interface and redraw
        GroupBox dynamicGroup = new GroupBox();
        dynamicGroup.Text = dynamicLabel.Text;
        dynamicGroup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 325);
        dynamicGroup.Location = button1.Location;
        dynamicGroup.Name = "dynamicGroupBox" + anzahlModule;
        dynamicGroup.Visible = true;

        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelComboBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelTextBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelTextBox2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelInhalt);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelInhalt2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelPictures);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelCheckBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelCheckBox2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelLink);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(LabelLink2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicUeberschrift);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicUeberschrift2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicComboBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicPictureBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicCheckBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicCheckBox2);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicLinkBox);
        dynamicGroup.Controls.Add(dynamicLinkBox2);
        panel1.Controls.Add(dynamicGroup);
```

this works if i add the stuff directly to panel1, but not when adding it to the groupboxes.

Can someone help my by giving me an idea on where the probleme might be or tell me what is actually wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're adding many `GroupBox` with same `Location` value - that will cause displaying of only first GroupBox

Comment: Okay I think I might have to explain the problem a bit better. I have multiple groupBoxes which are all being displayed. The first one is showing every textBox, label and so on that has been added to it. The second one is being displayed but seems to be empty. this returns for every following groupbox, so 1 is okay, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found my error and it is actually very simple, i was just too blind to see it :) I have positioned my textBoxes and so on in relation to a button that i afterwards moved. And that means that i tryed to display e.g. a label at point 750 / 300 in a group box that only has a size of 600x325, so it can not be visible. @Mikhail Neofitov thanks for the tip with multiple boxes at the same location, that lead to a solution.